# is it possible to run master and slave on same jvm in Spring remote partition batch jobs

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

Iam desiging a distributed remote partitioning batch jobs application with multiple nodes. All the nodes(jvm) will be master and slave will also be running in the same jvm. 
Is it possible to have master and slave on the same jvm? iam trying to test this but it is causing issues, seems spring remote partition doesnt allow running master and slave on same jvm?
please help.

Comment: Why use remote partitioning for this?  We provide a `TaskExecutorPartitionHandler` for single JVM use cases...

Comment: It is remote partitioning with 4 machines, but i need all the nodes to act as master and slave both, so that if one node goes down other will serve.

Answer (score 0):

Vikas, you can run a master and Slave in the same JVM, for example, I have run 1 master and 6 slave applications in my local JVM. Master and slaves run as separate java processes. Slaves listen to ActiveMq and gets triggered when master adds a stepexecution to the queue.